# Weird "e+08" values doing resizing of an 2D dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

Im trying to do a function that resizes a matrix made of dynamic arrays given 2 parametres: the new amount of rows and the new amount of columns. My problem is that when I size it to a larger matrix than the original one the new values that should be 0 are something like -4.31602e+08. Shouldn't be 0 if i don't set a value and just initialize the array?

```
void Matrix::resize(int nRows, int nColumns) {
    float** aux = new float* [nRows];

    for (int i = 0; i < nRows;i++) {
        aux[i] = new float[nColumns];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_nColumns; j++) {
            if (i < nRows && j < nColumns) {
                aux[i][j] = m_matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m_nRows; ++i)
        delete[] m_matrix[i];
    delete[] m_matrix;


    m_matrix = aux;

    m_nRows = nRows;
    m_nColumns = nColumns;

}
```

Comment: not 100% this is what is happening, hence not an answer: to properrly initialize the array you need: `new float[nColumns]{};`

Comment: `Shouldn't be 0 if i don't set a value`, no that is not correct. Dynamically allocated memory does not get initialised to zero by default.

Comment: Nevermind, comment was wrong.  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: yes, because to incorrectly assume that a float is initialized at 0;

Comment: Other than that the code looks correct, though it is not *exception safe*.

Comment: In such a case, a tool like *valgrind* would help you to detect use of uninitialised variables

Comment: Tip : When copying from the old array to the new array, you can put `if (i < nRows)` before the inner loop to potentially save a lot of time. `i` and `nRows` are not changed by the inner loop.

Comment: When dynamically allocating an array of any basic type - like `float` OR pointers, the elements are uninitialised - and accessing their values gives undefined behaviour   You are assuming - incorrectly - they are guaranteed to be initialised to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly assume that a float is initialized at 0.

Try to compile the following code

```
float f;
std::cout << f;
```

.. compiler at least says "warning: 'f' is used uninitialized". But probably prints 0 after all.

Now try

```
float* fp = new float;
std::cout << *fp;
delete fp;
```

Compiler doesn't warn, but you are printing random memory contents...
Accessing uninitialized variables is undefined behavior.

edit: a smart pointer will initialize the value for you by the way

```
auto fp = std::make_unique<float>();
std::cout << *fp << '\n';
```

Comment: I would add the precision that the problem this answer describes occurs when the resize increases one of the matrix's dimensions. For example when you add rows the new rows are uninitialized.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not _anything_ ;) but yes.

Comment: It is not random.  Underlying memory content is 0xcdcdcdcd, googles well.

Comment: @HansPassant That is not required and should not be expected. This is a value some platforms initialized new memory to in debug configurations to help track down errors.

Comment: It *is* expected, used to diagnose UB in a program.  Google "0xdeadbeef" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant It can be expected *on some platforms*. It is not a fact about C++.

Comment: You googled 0xcdcdcdcd and out popped "use wandbox"?  299 posts at SO is enough for everybody.

Comment: @JHBonarius That prints the address pointed to by `i`. Using `*i` would be a more accurate example. But none-the-less, you cannot make a general predict on what the result of that code with `*i` will be unless your environment otherwise provides additional guaranties. For example [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/81cjMT) seems to zero out all its memory (possibly for confidentiality) which is as conformant as any token value you could place there for debugging purposes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux WOOPSIE! let's forget that ever happened